# Storing user in database within Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working with Firebase and I'm having some troubles. When creating a new user, I am able to store it in my database, but later, when accessing to another component it fails.

```
//Register a new user in our system
  registerUserByEmail(email: string, pass: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
      .then(res => {
        this.email = res.user.email;
        let user = {
          email: this.email,
          goal: "",
          previousGoals: [],
          progress: {
            accomplishedToday: false,
            completedGoals: 0,
            daysInRow: 0,
            unlockedBadges: []
          }
        };
        // store in database
        new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
          this.firestore
            .collection("users")
            .add(user)
            .then(
              res => {
                console.log(res.id);
                this.isAuthenticated = true;
                this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
              },
              err => reject(err)
            );
        });
      });
  }
```

I believe that this piece of code is basically registering as a user the email and storing it successfully into my database (checked it).

Nevertheless, when rendering `home.component` or `/dashboard`

**home.component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.setAuthStatusListener();
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
    this.data.getUser().subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user.payload.data();
    });
  }
```

**data.service**

```
getUser() {
    return this.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(this.currentUser.uid)
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

I get the following error
**ERROR**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by the time you call `getUser` the user hasn't been authenticated yet.

The simple fix to get rid of the error is to check for this condition in your DataService's `getUser`:

```
getUser() {
  if (this.currentUser) {
    return this.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(this.currentUser.uid)
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

---

Given this sequence of calls however, I think there may be a better way to handle your use-case:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.setAuthStatusListener();
  this.getUser();
}
```

Since you're [attaching an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you probably want to only start watching the user's data in Firestore once the user has actually been authenticated.

Once simple way to do that is to call out to your DataService's `getUser()` method from within the auth state listener, once the user is authenticated. Something like this:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    this.getUser(); // call the DataService's getUser method
  }
});
```